# Why did my water stop getting hot and my stove doesn't do anything

Tags: wiring, thermostat, hot-water, heater, voltage

Cold water coming from the hot water heater. Changed the bottom  heating elament that was bad and let the tank refill. Turned power back on and waited an hour, turned  the water on to see if it was hot yet it's still cold coming from the tank. Tried to test how much  voltage was coming from the top and bottom elaments, the electric tester is giving two different voltage levels low voltage on the top element high voltage  on the  bottom element.

What is a normal voltage, I've checked the breakers all breakers are good.

Comment: What voltages did you get in each spot? What are you seeing at the supply, both line to line and line to ground each side?

Comment: Where does the stove come into this? You asked about it in the title question, but never mention it in the body of your question? Are you 100% certain you got the heating elements of the water heater installed correctly? Are you still having this issue a month later?

Answer (score 0):

Stove and Boiler are high energy devices.

They run on 2 phases. If you are in US you should have 240 Volt phase to phase or 120 Volt phase to ground.

If you have lost a phase contact your electricity supplier to fix the transformer.